# How to duplicate every index of an array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I'm struggling with this because all search engine results are about find duplicates in array. And I want exactly the opposite.

I have an array of colors:

`const colors = ["#fff", "#666", "#000"];`

How do I simply duplicate or triplicate every one of its indexes?

**x2:** `["#fff", "#fff", "#666", "#666", "#000", "#000"];`

**x3:** `["#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#666", "#666", "#666", "#000", "#000", "#000"];`

**x...**

Edit:

After o lot of negative votes I was compelled to say that I'm not a JS developer. I appreciate all the answers and effort. Thanks SO community.

Comment: `["#fff", "#666", "#000"].flatMap(el => [el, el])`

Comment: Thank you @AndyRay ! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: I already did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general case, you can use the array constructor with `fill` and `flatMap`:

```js
console.log(['abc', 123, 'xyz'].flatMap(el => Array(3).fill(el)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have trouble finding the answer to your question because technically you want to duplicate the *values* at each index, not the indices themselves.

One way to do this is to build an array with every element being an array with 2 items in it, then flatten the whole thing. As in build: `[["#fff", "#fff"], ["#666", "#666"]]` and then call `.flat()` on it to flatten it. Most functional languages, including Javascript, provide a `flatMap()` function to do just that:

```
["#fff", "#666", "#000"].flatMap(el => [el, el])
```

You can triple the elements by building a bigger innner array:

```
["#fff", "#666", "#000"].flatMap(el => [el, el, el])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made more general function *called* `duplicate` takes two *arguments* one *arr* the array we want to iterate and the other is *times* number of times you want duplicate each value
Using [`flatmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
function duplicate(arr, times){
  return arr.flatMap(x=>Array(times).fill(x))
}
const colors = ["#fff", "#666", "#000"];
console.log("x2", duplicate(colors,2))
console.log("x2", duplicate(colors,3))
```